# Proverb for good-bye e-mail

Tags: idiom

My German colleague is leaving the company, and I want to write him a good email in English. However, at the end of the email, I want to use a good German proverb for “good bye and keep in touch”.

Can you please suggest some good proverbs in German for “good bye and keep in touch”?

Comment: why someone downvoted this question ?

Comment: Indeed. Why downvote instead of vote to close?

Comment: If you do not like a question put a comment or the reason. Such a unreasonable sterile steps just because of your lack of ability to answer a question produces nothing.

Comment: Anonyme Downvotes sind legitim und in Übereinstimmung mit den Absichten der Plattformbetreiber - kein Grund in Spekulationen auszubrechen. Bei einem Mouseover kann man lesen, was die Gründe für ein Downvote sein sollen. "Does not show research" wäre eine naheliegende Erklärung.

Comment: -1 Sorry. Just like five other users, I did downvote because you got an answer and you were picky in something you should have specified in your question, and not in the comments below that answer.

Comment: ok.Understood and Accepted.

Answer (score 7):

> Mach's gut und lass mal von Dir hören.

would be a rather informal way of putting it.

More formal would be

> Auf Wiedersehen, ich hoffe, wir bleiben in Kontakt.

Comment: Hi Thorsten Dittmar , many thanks for answer but it would be helpful to have some proverb in German for saying something like , "a good thing ended in a good way" or "A good ending is a good start of our future relationship"

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any proverb that means what you want.

Comment: Many thanks Thorsten for help. +1.

Comment: "Jedes Ende ist ein neuer Anfang!" but it's ambigious if the ending was good or bad. It can also be an advise after the breakup of an relationship. I would write the sentences from @Thorsten DIttmars answer

Comment: Yes , this is helpful Iris. +1.

Comment: @Iris that doesn't cover the "keep in touch part" really.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, yes you are right. Like I wrote, I would prefer your answera for an Email.

Answer (score 3):

> Aus den Augen, aus dem Sinn

is a common proverbial expression for the opposite of what you want, and most Germans know it. So you could write something like

> Aus den Augen soll nicht heißen aus dem Sinn.

I've heard this said a few times at farewell. It fits your requirements, but it's a bit of a platitude.

Comment: I assumed you can read German. If not, I'll edit in a translation.

Comment: +1. yes thanks.